# How to combine two graphics in Mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

So, I have a task, where I need to make a graphic which shows how changes Volume of water in a vessel depending on water level inside. [image: Picture of vessel, consisting of one cilinder and two conuses]

I've found formulas (H < R and H > R), made 2 plots and combined them, but I have a gap between them. What could be wrong?

```
p1 = Plot[
  L*1/2*R^2*(2*ArcCos[(R - λ)/R] - Sin[2*ArcCos[(R - λ)/R]]) + 
  2/3*R^2*l*(ArcCos[(R - λ)/R] - 2*Sin[ArcCos[(R - λ)/R]]*
  Cos[ArcCos[(R - λ)/R]] + Cos[ArcCos[(R - λ)/R]]^3*
  Log[Tan[ArcCos[(R - λ)/R]/2 + \[Pi]/4]]) /. H -> λ, {λ, 0, 2 R}];
p2 = Plot[
  L*Pi*R^2 - L*(1/2*R^2*(2*ArcCos[(λ - R)/R] - 
  Sin[2*ArcCos[(λ - R)/R]])) + 2/3*l*Pi*R^2 - 
  1/3*R^2*l*(ArcCos[(λ - R)/R] - 2 Sin[ArcCos[(λ - R)/R]] *
  Cos[ArcCos[(λ - R)/R]] + Cos[ArcCos[(λ - R)/R]]^3*
  Log[Tan[ArcCos[(λ - R)/R]/2 + \[Pi]/4]]) /. H -> λ, {λ, 0, 2 R}];
Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> Automatic]]
```

(I'm sorry I don't know haw I can put this code in a more beautiful way)

And as a result I have such a graphic
[image: the graphic]

Comment: Did you try to run a `Simplify` over your expressions. You have terms like `Cos[ ArcCos[ z ] ]` which is `z` other terms that can easily be simplified are `Sin[ ArcCos[ z ] ]`, `Tan[ ArcCos[ z ] ]`, and `Sin[ 2 ArcCos[ z ] ]`. ( even by hand or, as you have *Mathematica* with `Simplify[ ]` ) That might help to find typos as mentioned by the answer of Bill

Comment: I can not reproduce, H is not defined for instance, R value should be defined, please provide a minimal working example. Otherwise, I would suggest [Piecewise](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) built-in function

Answer (score 0):

If I try

```
Limit[{firstexpr,secondexpr}, λ->R]
```

to see what each of your expressions are as Lambda gets very close to R (I did that because just substituting via `λ->R` ends up with zero*infinity) then I find

```
{1/6(2 l+3 L) Pi R^2, 1/6(3 l+3 L) Pi R^2}
```

So... I am guessing you have a tiny typo in one or the other of those expressions. That would potentially explain the discontinuity in your graph.

From that can you possibly track down and find the flaw?

p.s. The way I put Greek characters into posts here is to scrape-n-paste the appropriate characters from [Greek Character Table](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html) into my post.